# My Regex not works

Tags: php, regex

I made a php regex robot to fetch some info from a website but it does not work for some of them with this format:
the main code is:

```
<a class="name" href="http://sitesite.com/go/lid/1111/" target=_blank><font style="color: #006400;font-size: 16px;"><b>SomeText</b></font></a>
```

and my PHP regex is:

```
#<a (.*?)" href="http://sitesite\.com/go/lid/([0-9]*)/" (.*?)><font style="color: #006400;font-size: 16px;"><b>(.*?)</b></font></a>#
```

I changed it in many shapes but didn't work. What is the trick?

Comment: Use error reporting. Here's your error `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '0'`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at delimiting characters, being "#" and you have another "#" in the middle of regexp:

> color: #006400

Fix your code like this:

```
$txt = '<a class="name" href="http://sitesite.com/go/lid/1111/" target=_blank><font style="color: #006400;font-size: 16px;"><b>SomeText</b></font></a>';
preg_match('#<a (.*?)" href="http://sitesite\.com/go/lid/([0-9]*)/" (.*?)><font style="color: .006400;font-size: 16px;"><b>(.*?)</b></font></a>#', $txt, $m);
print_r($m);
```

http://ideone.com/zoZgez

Instead "#" I used "." inside regexp.

Comment: Why not just change the delimiter? `.` can be anything (excluding new line).

Comment: Awesome, It worked. Thank you so much. I have a question php regex robot does not work for fetching from a Ddos protected website?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understood your question right. Are you trying to extract information only from that `<a>` tag? Does the `href` always starts with `http://sitesite.com/go/lid/...` or you need something more generic?

If you really need to match the href and the font tag you could use:

`^<a (.*?) href="http:\/\/sitesite.com\/go\/lid\/([0-9]*)\/"\s(.*?)><font style="color: #006400;font-size: 16px;"><b>(.*?)<\/b><\/font><\/a>$`

Note that basically I only escaped the slashes and removed the `#` from the extremes of your regex.

#### A live example in [liveregex.net](http://liveregex.net/57dbaedff0a33)

If you need something more generic I guess you could use this:

`^<a (.*?) href="(?:.*\/)([0-9]*)\/"\s(.*?)>(?:.*)<b>(.*?)<\/b>(?:.*)<\/a>$`

#### A live example in [liveregex.net](http://liveregex.net/57dbac14ec7c2)